# How to convert Date format to numbers to plot density curve

Tags: r

I have a data set that has a column named date (with 6000 rows)in this form:

```
df$newdate<-format(df$newdate, "%a %H:%M:%S");
Mon 16:16:59
Tue 11:09:55 
Thu 08:49:42
...
```

I like to plot the density curve. In order to do that I need to convert dates to the numerical value. I would like to use this formula:

(day of week-1)*24 + hour + minute/60 + second/3600

so for example in the first row of the new date column, I want to have
(Monday-1)*24+16+16/60+59/3600

I have a hard time extracting weekdays and convert them to numbers.
Here is what I did so far:

```
test<-strptime(as.character(df$newdate),format="%a %H:%M:%S")
x<-hour(test)+ (minute(test)/60) + (second(test) / 3600)
plot(density(x));
```

for some reason when I ran weekdays(test) only one weekday shows up.
Could you please help me figure this out?

Comment: Could you include your data using `dput(df[1:3,])`?

Comment: It seems that you have `newdate` as a POSIX date column? But then every time you use it you `format` it so it becomes `character` class, then `strptime` it to convert it back to `POSIX`? `test<-strptime(as.character(df$newdate),format="%a %H:%M:%S")` seems like a long way to write `test <- df$newdate`...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a decimal version of hours since start of week. I think this should work, assuming `newdate` is a datetime object and hasn't been `format`ted to `character` class first:

```
library(lubridate)
df$week_hours = as.numeric(difftime(x, floor_date(x, unit = "weeks"), units = "hours"))
```

Comment: so what I want to do is to convert each date row to a number [0,24*7) based on the formula above. For example in row one I like to have (Monday-1)*24+16+16/60+59/3600)

Comment: @Statfellow ...and that formula gives the number of hours since the start of the week. Which is also what my answer does. I *might* be off by a day, but I'm not really sure since you don't provide an input/desired output pair, and I'm not quite sure what "Monday - 1" means - I think you either want the number of hours since midnight on Sunday morning or midnight on Monday morning. My answer uses midnight on Sunday morning.

Comment: Unless this is a homework assignment, and you are required to use *that formula* manually rather than a way to get the same answer relying on well-tested built-in functions?

Comment: If you'd share your data reproducibly, with `dput(your_data[1:3, ])` then we will get a copy/pasteable version of the first 3 rows, including all structure and class information. We can then demonstrate the code on the sample of your data, and make sure we are getting the right answer.